Isometric conversion from screen coordinates to an $N \times M$ grid when not at true origin?
Given a pre-rendered image and its associated 2d array of $N \times M$ size, is there a system of equations that can calculate from screen $(x,y)$ to $(\text{grid}x, \text{grid}y)$ in my array? The caveat is that the 2d array only holds data/dimensions for the actual tiles seen in the image; it does not include data that are empty space (transparent pixels). However, the pre-rendered image shows both the tiles and empty space.
Basically, what I'm trying to do is make a game where when my mouse hovers over a tile in the pre-rendered image, I would like to know the exact $(\text{grid}x, \text{grid}y)$ in my 2d array that the tile corresponds to.
When the pre-rendered image is displayed, the screen origin $(0,0)$ starts at the top left corner, increases as you go right for $X$, and increases when you go down for $Y$. Since the tiles are not rendered at the screen origin, I need to offset the $X$ coordinate by some amount to get the true $(0,0)$ origin for the starting tile.
For this example, I generated a $20 \times 30$ isometric tiles onto the following pre-rendered image.

Notice the screen origin is top-left, but the tile origin is way over to the right.
Here are some details for the example:
    tile_width = 128      # tile width in pixels
    tile_height = 64      # tile height in pixels
    image_width = 3200    # pre-rendered image width in pixels
    image_height = 1600   # pre-rendered image height in pixels

    mouse_x       # Current Mouse X position on screen
    mouse_y       # Current Mouse Y position on screen

I attempt my equations for converting from screen -> grid:
    offset_x = 0        <--- !! Not sure how to calculate this?

    grid_x = floor( (mouse_y/tile_height) + ((mouse_x+offset_x)/tile_width)
    grid_y = floor( -(mouse_x+offset_x)/tile_width) + (mouse_y/tile_height) )

But even without the proper offset, these equations don't seem correct. I.e., at tile origin $(0,0)$, this formula gives me $(15,-15)$ at screen coordinate (1919,20).
I'm not sure if it helps, but this is my 2D data array, which holds just data on the 20x30 tiles themselves:
tiles = [[42, 42, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
            [42, 42, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
            [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
            [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
            [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
            [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
            [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
            [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
            [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
            [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 42, 42, 42, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
            [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 42, 42, 42, 42, 42, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
            [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 42, 42, 42, 42, 42, 42, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
            [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 42, 42, 42, 42, 42, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
            [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 42, 42, 42, 42, 42, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
            [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 42, 42, 42, 42, 42, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
            [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 42, 42, 42, 42, 42, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
            [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 42, 42, 42, 42, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
            [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 42, 42, 42, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
            [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 42, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
            [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
            [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
            [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
            [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
            [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
            [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
            [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
            [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 42],
            [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 42],
            [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 42],
            [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 42, 42, 42, 42]]

For validation, I manually found these screen -> grid coordinates:
screen      ->    grid

(1918,23)   ->   (0,0)
(1908,49)   ->   (0,0)
(2048,69)   ->   (2,0)
(3114,642)  ->   (19,0)
(1283,1500) ->   (18,28)
(124,926)   ->   (0,28)
(52,952)    ->   (0,29)
(93,968)    ->   (0,29)

Is this possible to do? If so, how can I figure out what the proper $X$ offset should be and the correct system of equations for conversion? I've tried a few other equations I've found online, but I think the issue there is they assume all tiles are rendered at the true origin, whereas my true origin is initially unknown and has to be based off an $N \times M$ dimension rather than a perfect $N \times N$ diamond. Any help is appreciated!

First translate the screen coordinate to make $(0,0)$ mean the origin, i.e. let
$x'=x-M*tile\_width/2=x-30*64$,
$y'=y$.
Then the grid coordinates are
$$(x_g,y_g)=\left(\left\lfloor\frac{2y'-x'}{128}\right\rfloor, \left\lfloor\frac{2y'+x'}{128}\right\rfloor\right)$$
The $\lfloor\ \rfloor$ brackets mean rounding down to an integer. You don't have to round down of course if you want to know the precise position inside the tile.
Strictly speaking the formula divides $y'$ by $tile\_height$ and $x'$ by $tile\_width$, but I rewrote it to look nicer. It is actually this:
$$(x_g,y_g)=\left(\frac{y'}{tile\_height}-\frac{x'}{tile\_width}, \frac{y'}{tile\_height}+\frac{x'}{tile\_width}\right)$$
To go in the other direction, use the following:
$$(x',y')=\left( (y_g-x_g)\frac{tile\_width}2, (y_g+x_g)\frac{tile\_height}2\right)$$

Thanks for looking into my question! Could you further expand your answer like I'm a beginner math student? How did you know that the gridx  had to be 2y' - x' / 128?
Also, is there a way to reverse the equations, Ie: (gridx, gridy) -> (x,y)? I tried to reverse (xg,yg), and I got x = -(128*xg - 2y') + 64M , but then I realized this isn't possible since I don't know anything about y' from just (gridx, gridy).

Thanks! When going from grid -> screen, do I also have to translate the origin too? ie, x = ((( Yg - Xg)(tile_width)) / 2 ) + M(tile_width/2)? Since y' = y, that doesn't no calculation is needed here.

am I calculating the X value wrong? For coordinate (18,28), using x = ((Yg - Xg)*(64 ) + (30*64)), I get x = 2560. Using just your formula, x'=(Yg - Xg)(64) = 640. The X coordinate should be roughly around 1283? In the first one I substituted your x' equation for translating to the true (0,0) origin, but the resulting X is almost double.

I marked the answer as correct, thank you so much for helping with the original question. I'm still having trouble with the grid->screen conversion, the numbers I'm getting are too big for x if I substitute in the x' formula (to account for the (0,0) translate to origin). If you could clarify this point that would be really awesome!
